# Use D3 to plot points on "scrollytelly" Mapbox GL JS map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to create a "scrollytelly" map with dots that change color as the user scrolls. The dot's color is dictated by a value in an array. There are five arrays, one for each year. As the user scrolls, I want the color to transition from one array's value to the next, while keeping the basemap the same.

So far I've:

1. Plotted all the points using D3 from one array onto a Mapbox GL JS base map.

```
   mapboxgl.accessToken = 'myaccesstoken';
            
            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                container: 'map', // container id
                style: 'mapbox://styles/as9934/cknz91yxz0d4h17qg1nr26p0o', // style URL
                center: [-122.27, 37.8], // starting position [lng, lat]
                zoom: 12 // starting zoom
            });

            function project(data) {
                return map.project(new mapboxgl.LngLat(data[0], data[1]));
            }

            var container = map.getCanvasContainer();
            
            var svg = d3
                .select(container)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", "100%")
                .attr("height", "2000")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("z-index", 2);

           var data = [[]] //array of values excluded to save space
           
           var color  = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0.00, 0.25])
                .range(["#006ba6", "#a6640e"]);

           var dots = svg
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("r", 8)
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .style("fill", function(data){
                    return color(data[4])
                })
          function render() {
                dots
                    .attr("cx", function(data) {
                        return project(data).x;
                    })
                    .attr("cy", function(data) {
                        return project(data).y;
                    });
                }
            render();
            map.on("viewreset", render);
            map.on("move", render);
            map.on("moveend", render);
            map.scrollZoom.disable();
```

2. Experimented with the [graph-scroll.js template](https://github.com/1wheel/graph-scroll) using only one dot that changes color

```
...
<div id='container' class='container-1'>
  <div id='graph'></div>
  <div id='sections'>
    <div>
      <h3>Section #1</h3>
      This is section #1.<br></br>
      This is section #1.<br></br>
      This is section #1.<br></br>
      This is section #1.<br></br>

    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>Section #2</h3>
      This is section #2.<br></br>
      This is section #2. <br></br>
      This is section #2. <br></br>
      This is section #2. <br></br>
    </div>


    <div>
      <h3>Section #3</h3>
    This is section #3.<br></br>
    This is section #3.<br></br>
    This is section #3.<br></br>
    This is section #3.<br></br>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h3>Section #4</h3>
    This is section #4.<br></br>
    This is section #4.<br></br>
    This is section #4.<br></br>
    This is section #4.<br></br>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<h1 id='source'>Footer</h1>

<div> 
<p> twas a bright and shining day</p>
</div>

<script src="d3v4+jetpack.js"></script>
<script src="graph-scroll.js"></script>
<script>

var oldWidth = 0
function render(){
  if (oldWidth == innerWidth) return
  oldWidth = innerWidth

  var width = height = d3.select('#graph').node().offsetWidth
  var r = 40


  if (innerWidth <= 925){
    width = innerWidth
    height = innerHeight*.7
  }

  // return console.log(width, height)

  var svg = d3.select('#graph').html('')
    .append('svg')
      .attrs({width: width, height: height})

  var circle = svg.append('circle')
      .attrs({cx: width/2, cy: height-100, r: r})

  var colors = ['orange', 'purple', 'steelblue', 'pink', 'black']
  var gs = d3.graphScroll()
      .container(d3.select('.container-1'))
      .graph(d3.selectAll('container-1 #graph'))
      .eventId('uniqueId1')  // namespace for scroll and resize events
      .sections(d3.selectAll('.container-1 #sections > div'))
      // .offset(innerWidth < 900 ? innerHeight - 30 : 200)
      .on('active', function(i){
        circle.transition().duration(1000)
          .transition()
            .style('fill', colors[i])
      })

  d3.select('#source')
      .styles({'margin-bottom': window.innerHeight - 450 + 'px', padding: '100px'})
}
render()
d3.select(window).on('resize', render)


</script>
```

3. Experimented with the [interactive storytelling demo](https://www.mapbox.com/solutions/interactive-storytelling) from the Mapbox team.

```
var config = {
    style: 'mapbox://styles/as9934/cknz91yxz0d4h17qg1nr26p0o',
    accessToken: 'myaccesstoken',
    showMarkers: false,
    markerColor: '#3FB1CE',
    theme: 'dark',
    use3dTerrain: false,
    title: 'title goes here',
    subtitle: 'A descriptive and interesting subtitle to draw in the reader',
    byline: 'By me',
    footer: 'Data from x.',
    chapters: [
        {
            id: 'section-1',
            alignment: 'left',
            hidden: false,
            title: 'Display Title',
            image: '',
            description: 'Section 1',
            location: {
                center: [-122.27, 37.8],
                zoom: 12,
                pitch: 0,
                bearing: 0
            },
            mapAnimation: 'flyTo',
            rotateAnimation: false,
            callback: '',
            onChapterEnter: [
                // {
                //     layer: 'layer-name',
                //     opacity: 1,
                //     duration: 5000
                // }
            ],
            onChapterExit: [
                // {
                //     layer: 'layer-name',
                //     opacity: 0
                // }
            ]
        },
...
```

How can I make these pieces work together?  It seems like 1 & 3 are more compatible than  1 & 2, but I don't know enough to be sure. I'm also open to other solutions, if you think they will be easier.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you meant change color on zoom in/out, not on scroll. Am I right?

Comment: No, I mean on scroll. I turned scroll-zoom off on the basemap.

Comment: I can write a sample that handles scroll position change of an `<svg>` element within its parent `<div>` and changes its dots' colors. I'm not sure it's what you need...